# Drawing App in swift, slow performance & low FPS

Tags: ios, swift, performance, drawing, frame-rate

I am trying to create a drawing app , using this code to draw lines but it is giving a very slow performance

```
 func drawLineNew(_ prevPoint1 : CGPoint,_ prevPoint2 : CGPoint ,_ currentPoint : CGPoint){
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(ImageView.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    ImageView.image?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height))
    var mid1 = CGPoint.init(x: (prevPoint1.x + prevPoint2.x)*0.5, y: (prevPoint1.y + prevPoint2.y)*0.5)
    var mid2 = CGPoint.init(x: ((currentPoint.x) + prevPoint1.x)*0.5, y: ((currentPoint.y) + prevPoint1.y)*0.5)
    context?.move(to: prevPoint2)
    context?.addCurve(to: mid2, control1: mid1, control2: prevPoint1)
    context?.setLineCap(CGLineCap.round)
    context?.setLineWidth(brushWidth)
    context?.setStrokeColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: opacity)
    context?.setBlendMode(CGBlendMode.normal )
    //context?.setShouldAntialias(true)
    context?.strokePath()
    ImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    ImageView.alpha = 1.0
    self.prevPoint1 = mid2
    //context?.clear(CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), size: ImageView.frame.size))
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    lastPoint = currentPoint
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? How many times does this method get call and when? is it for each touch? is it just once ? Here you are actually creating and image, is that what you want ? please provide more context, also on what device is it slow, what are the parameters... etc

Answer (score 0):

The performance is slow when you draw too much lines. Consider optimizing the performance by not drawing all lines depending on the size of your drawing area and which distance a pixel is representing on the displayed scale.